# Delete Event Notification while using MS Graph API (Office JS)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We are implementing MS Outlook Addin feature using the Graph API v1.0 and we noticed that   deleting event sends cancel notification which we want to stop. Could you please suggest on how to disable cancel notifications? The good thing that Secondary calendar does not send the notification when deleting events and we would like the similar behavior for Primary calendar.. Please suggest if there is any way to achieve this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

What we tried - We tried deleting events from secondary calendar, and notifications does not trigger.
What we are expecting - When deleting event from PRIMARY calendar, cancel notifications SHOULD NOT triggered.